# Why is my function causing a TypeError <function> is not a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I am calling a function that appears to obviously be a function, but I keep getting TypeError: [function name] is not a function.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error.

main.ts

```
import someFunction from './someFunction'
export const baseUrl = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname

someFunction(); //causing TypeError: someFunction is not a function
```

someFunction.ts

```
import {Foo} from './Foo'
export default function someFunction(): void {
    //some code here
    let foo = new Foo();
    //some other code here
}
```

Foo.ts

```
import {baseUrl} from './main'
export class Foo{
    constructor()

    private someRandomPrivateFunction(): void {
        //some code
        let url = baseUrl + "other/stuff"; //removing this line fixes the TypeError
        //some other code
    }
}
```

Some details on the background items being used.

Typescript is 1.8 targeting ES5, and generating modules using AMD.

RequireJS is 2.2.0 and data-main points to main

I was testing in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me way too long to figure out, but eventually it boiled down to a circular reference.

In `Foo.ts` if the reference to `baseUrl` is removed, then everything else works fine because `baseUrl` is a dependency coming from `main.ts`

To fix the problem, `baseUrl` just needed to be moved to a different file `baseUrl.ts`

Some painful lessons drawn from this experience:

1. Nothing should be dependent on `main.ts`... that one should have been obvious.
2. The error messages spawning from a circular reference can be very vague, completely unrelated, and several layers away from the actual problem, so don't depend on error messages to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Glad you fixed it on your end.  Just wanted to chime in and say I tried your example above and was not seeing the `TypeError` you were seeing.

Comment: @mrand01 I added some details to the question that should help mimic what I was doing more accurately. Also, it may be worth noting that the `TypeError` was only at run time in Chrome. There were no indications of an error until I tried to run it.